# jQuery hyphens in animation

Tags: jquery

```
$this.animate(  {
                width: +=50,
                height: +=50,
                padding-right:50px
                }
```

along with the webkit/moz border attributes, I haven't been able to use any hyphenated css properties. Putting it in quotes *("padding-right")* and removing the hyphen altogether *("paddingRight")* didn't fix it, on top of the latter not working with the webkit/moz attributes.

The error I get in Chrome's inspection tool is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XGp26/)**

When you have a hyphen you need to wrap it in quotes, otherwise it wont parse correctly giving you a syntax error. Note this isnt limited to jQuery properties, object properties in general.

```
$this.animate(  {
                width: '+=50',
                height: '+=50',
                'padding-right':50
                } );
```

j08692 is also correct in the comments, `paddingRight` will also work. http://docs.jquery.com/index.php?title=Effects/animate&redirect=no

Comment: paddingRight should also work. "Note that properties should be specified using camel case, e.g. "marginLeft" instead of "margin-left." http://docs.jquery.com/index.php?title=Effects/animate&redirect=no

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are not allowed in JavaScript variable names. To combat this problem, jQuery uses camel-casing for CSS property names.

For example, instead of `padding-right` you would use `paddingRight`.

Now that is out of the way, you also have another problem. `width: +=50` and `height: +=50` are incorrect. You are trying to increment by 50, but there is no variable to increment. I can see what you are trying to do and the following is probably what you need.

```
$this.animate({
  width: $this.width() + 50,
  height: $this.height() + 50,
  paddingRight: 50
});
```

Comment: Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property. - api.jquery.com/animate look at my fiddle which also works http://jsfiddle.net/XGp26/1/. He needs to wrap them in quotes.

Comment: You are missing the point. The way that works in jQuery, is by passing a string: "+=50". In yours and enche's code, you didn't do that. There for it is invalid JavaScript and throws the error `Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation`

Comment: I assume that's an error in his example, his syntax error (and the whole reason for his question) had to do with the hyphen.

Comment: Yes it was an error in his example. An error which you also copied across to your answer, and insisted I was wrong about. You are also correct that his question was about the hyphen, but with the second error still there, his code still wouldn't work. This is why I corrected both.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).animate({
  width: // set the width to what you want it to end//
  height: //set the height to what you want in the end
  paddingRight: "50px", // use quotes and commas
});
```